# ssh_config capture group (or similar)

Tags: ssh

I like to namespace (simple prefix) remote servers that share a common network disposition or other logical access/grouping.

Is there a way to reference the contents of the wildcard (capture group or entire match), in `ssh_config` ?
This would significantly simplify the config / keep entries to a minimum.

Coding them all manually would mean specifying 100+ `Host`s, with some yet-unknown or dynamic remote names.

E.g., ideally :

```
Host x-hop
  Hostname example.org

Host x-(*)
  ProxyJump x-hop
  Hostname  %1
  User      user
```

Meaning `ssh x-foo`, `ssh x-bar`, etc. would all take the shared hop by default.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. As a workaround you could create an alias that uses a different config file for these hosts. `alias ssh-x="ssh -F ~/config_x"` with the wanted configuration. It shouldn't make much difference if you call `ssh x-host` or `ssh-x host`.

Comment: Great solution, thanks! I'm trying something similar, ```ssh-x () { ssh -l user -J x-hop $@; }```. Alias seems like it would be safer, but I'm the only one using the function. Function saves a separate config I guess? Might try out both approaches. Maybe someday ```ssh_config``` will better support regex.